# How to add function after entering 4 letters in textfield swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitextfield

I could restrict the number of characters to be entered in textfield using the following function

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{

    let maxLength = 4

        if maxLength == 4 {

    let currentString: NSString = textField.text!
    let newString: NSString =
        currentString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    return newString.length <= maxLength

    }
    else
    {
    return true
    }
```

}

But now I need to go to the next screen when I enter the fourth character in the textfield.

How to add function at once the fourth character is entered?

Comment: Cant understand what you need, do you want to reuse this function for textfield on next screen?

Comment: you need to check that the entering character is 4th then direct push it from current view controller to next view controller

Comment: I Now I could limit the characters to make it type till fourth character but need to add an action function for moving to the next screen , while after typing the fourth character like pin entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1.** First of all, add this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged) // make sure it is the desired textField
```

Then add your function:

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text!.characters.count  == 4{
         let yourNewViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourNewViewControllerIdentifier")
         self.present(yourNewViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

**METHOD 2.**

**Step 1:** Conforming to `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
class yourClass: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{ //... 
}
```

and in viewDidLoad():

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

**Step 2:**

Implementing this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    if textField == yourTextField{ 
        if string.characters.count == 4{
             let yourNewViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourNewViewControllerIdentifier")
             self.present(yourNewViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)        

        }

    }
    else{
        // the other textfields
    }

      return true
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If you have any other questions make sure to ask

Comment: Thanks @Xcoder123 working great with slight modifications ..     textField.text!.characters.count == 4

Answer (score 4):

Try this

if string.characters.count == 4

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        if textField == self.yourTextField{
        if string.characters.count == 4{
           //do your task
        }
        else
        {
        return true
        }
      }else{
      return true 
}
    }
```

Comment: I am having more than one textfield, I need to implement for specific textfield and the above code is getting error missing return function bool..

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to :

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){

    print("Text changed: " + textField.text!)
    if(textField.Text.characters.count >3 ) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    let secondViewController =    self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```